# Store "No such file or directory" message in a variable

Tags: shell

I have script which internally calls another shell script. There is a possibility that the second script  does not exists. I want to write conditional executions after that. How can I store the message "No such file or directory" inside a variable?

```
OUTPUT=$(sh ../../bin/tools/myscript.sh)
sh: ../../bin/tools/myscript.sh: No such file or directory
[root@xxxx home]# echo $OUTPUT
```

The $OUTPUT should also print "No such file or directory" message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The message has been printed to stderr, so you have to catch stderr somehow:

```
OUTPUT=$(sh ../../bin/tools/myscript.sh 2>&1)
```

or something like

```
error_file=/tmp/stderr.$$
sh ../../bin/tools/myscript.sh 2>$error_file
OUTPUT=$(cat $error_file)
rm $error_file
```

depending on your concrete needs. Of course in your case, it would maybe make more sense to test the existence of `myscript.sh`, **before** you try to run it.

Answer (score 0):

The below code worked for me :

```
OUTPUT=$((sh ../../bin/tools/myscript.sh) 2>&1)
```